# How to return null for items not found in mongodb aggregation $in?

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Using the next example collection:

```
[
  { _id: ObjectId.createFromHexString("5c51eb681c9d44000091fffa"), name: "name1" },
  { _id: ObjectId.createFromHexString("5c51eb681c9d44000091fffb"), name: "name2" },
  { _id: ObjectId.createFromHexString("5c51eb681c9d44000091fffc"), name: "name3" },
  { _id: ObjectId.createFromHexString("5c51eb681c9d44000091fffe"), name: "name5" }
]
```

I have the next mongodb aggregation query:

```
const keys: ObjectId[] = [
  ObjectId.createFromHexString("5c51eb681c9d44000091fffe"),
  ObjectId.createFromHexString("5c51eb681c9d44000091fffd"),
  ObjectId.createFromHexString("5c51eb681c9d44000091fffc"),
  ObjectId.createFromHexString("5c51eb681c9d44000091fffb"),
];
const aggregation: AggregationCursor<TEntity> = collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: { $in: keys } } },
  { $addFields: { __order: { $indexOfArray: [keys, "$_id"] } } },
  { $sort: { __order: 1 } },
  { $project: { __order: 0 } },
]);

console.log(await aggregation.toArray());
```

The current result for the previous aggregation query is:

```
[
  { _id: 5c51eb681c9d44000091fffe, name: "name5" },
  { _id: 5c51eb681c9d44000091fffc, name: "name3" },
  { _id: 5c51eb681c9d44000091fffb, name: "name2" }
]
```

As you can see, the length of the result is less than the length of the searched items. I want get a result the same length of the searched items, replacing the items not found by "null".

summarizing, if it is possible I want a result as the next:

```
[
  { _id: 5c51eb681c9d44000091fffe, name: "name5" },
  null
  { _id: 5c51eb681c9d44000091fffc, name: "name3" },
  { _id: 5c51eb681c9d44000091fffb, name: "name2" },
]
```

I pretend use this with a Facebook DataLoader, where the result length need have the same length of the searched items. Otherwise I get the next error:

```
TypeError: DataLoader must be constructed with a function which 
accepts Array<key> and returns Promise<Array<value>>, but the function 
did not return a Promise of an Array of the same length as the Array 
of keys.
```

Here is the full class, in case it can help:

```
import DataLoader from "dataloader";
import { AggregationCursor, Collection, ObjectId } from "mongodb";

export default class BaseLoaders<TEntity> {
    private LoaderId: DataLoader<ObjectId, TEntity>;

    public constructor(collection: Collection<TEntity>) {
        this.LoaderId = new DataLoader((keys) => this.BatchId(collection, keys), {
            cacheKeyFn: (key) => key.toHexString(),
        });
    }

    public get id(): DataLoader<ObjectId, TEntity> {
        return this.LoaderId;
    }

    private async BatchId(collection: Collection<TEntity>, keys: ObjectId[]): Promise<TEntity[]> {
        const aggregation: AggregationCursor<TEntity> = collection.aggregate([
            { $match: { _id: { $in: keys } } },
            { $addFields: { __order: { $indexOfArray: [keys, "$_id"] } } },
            { $sort: { __order: 1 } },
            { $project: { __order: 0 } },
        ]);

        return aggregation.toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know the Mongo API won't give you `null` in it's result set in any situation involving `Array` return types.  But why would you want to do this anyway? You know what you sent in to the DB and you know what you received. Some array manipulation will give you all the `_id`s for which nothing was returned, and you could replace those elements with `null`s.

Comment: could you explain what you're dealing with mongo id's ? what's your goal. Could help you goal . Try to explain in a data (business) oriented way. An ObjectId is a Mongo object .. why converting it to a String object ? losing indexing efficiency ?

Comment: @ethane - Yes, it is a solution, I can manipulate the result array in the Typescript code. But if it is possible, I am prefer delegate this work to mongodb.

Comment: @opotonil, I'm not sure you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: @Emmanuel - I have corrected my question, I hope it now to be more clear. I don't want convert ObjectIds to strings. I pretend use this with a Facebook DataLoader, where the result length need have the same length of the searched items.